# Is there a way to add a variable to a formula?

Tags: excel, variables, offset

Is there any way to add a variable to this formula so that $C$24 references a cell with =COUNTA formula in it?

```
=OFFSET(DATA!$C$1,0,0,COUNTA(DATA!$C$1:$C$24)-COUNTBLANK(DATA!$C$1:$C$24),1)
```

...becomes...

```
=OFFSET(DATA!$C$1,0,0,COUNTA(DATA!$C$1:($J$4))-COUNTBLANK(DATA!$C$1:($J$4)),1)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Thanx for looking,
Sam

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are probably easier methods to get to what you want.

Comment: I'm using a drop down menu that removes entries once they are used. I'd like to be able to add more entries to my data column without having to expand the formula each time to incorporate them. I have a data column with names that collate to 24 entries but this is variable.

Comment: So you want to reference the last cell with data in column C?

Comment: I'd like to count all the entries in the column otherwise my drop down list goes to infinity. DATA!A:A contains names; DATA!B:B contains =IF(COUNTIF(Timetable!$C$5:$E$15,$A1)>=1,"",ROW()); DATA!C:C contains =IF(ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1)+1>COUNT(B$1:B$24),"",INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(B$1:B$24,1+ROW($A1)-ROW($A$1)))).

Comment: Is this something you are putting in data validation or named range?

Comment: Yes, data validation. The formula I'm using is the OP. Data Validation is List =names which refers to DATA!C:C

Comment: I'm getting kicked out of work! I'll be back in 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

To reference the last Cell with data, avoiding the use of Volitile formula:

```
=DATA!$C$1:INDEX(DATA!$C:$C,MATCH("zzz",DATA!$C:$C))
```

Then no input needed it will grow or contract as the data changes.